# Python: creating dictionary from a bunch of "key: value" strings?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose I have loaded this into a list:

```
info = ['apple: 1', 'orange: 2', 'grape: 3']
```

How can I turn that into something like

```
info = {line[0]: line[1] for line.split(': ') in info}
```

So that I actually have a dict?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're very close!

```
>>> info = ['apple: 1', 'orange: 2', 'grape: 3']
>>> info = dict(line.split(': ') for line in info)
>>> info
{'orange': '2', 'grape': '3', 'apple': '1'}
```

You could do it the way you tried to in Python 2.7+, but you'd have to split the lines separately, so using `dict` is better.

Here's what I mean:

```
info = ['apple: 1', 'orange: 2', 'grape: 3']
info = {fruit:num for fruit, num in (line.split(': ') for line in info)}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write:

```
dict(tuple(line.split(': ')) for line in info)
```

Comment: fyi - dict (and set) comprehensions were also backported to 2.7.2

Comment: I know, but that doesn't make the code any clearer or shorter (see @senderle's use of it above). My use of `tuple` was unnecessary, as you can see in @senderle's answer.